# My condition for progress is invalid

Tags: java, android

Please help me for this project. This condition is for our game progress. The error here is when one of the if statements is correct, if you cast another button and got the answer correctly, the result doesn't add anymore.. help me please.. thanks a lot.. :DD

```
 try
    {
        if(questonedone==true)
        {
            btl1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f1);
            btl1.setEnabled(false);
            counter =  percent + 6.25 ;
            counter2 = percent2 + 1;
        }
        if(questtwodone==true)
        {
            btl2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f5);
            btl2.setEnabled(false);
            counter =  percent + 6.25 ;
            counter2 = percent2 + 1;
        }
        if(questthreedone==true)
        {
            btl3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f9);
            btl3.setEnabled(false);
            counter =  percent + 6.25 ;
            counter2 = percent2 + 1;
        }
        if(questfourdone==true)
        {
            btl4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f13);
            btl4.setEnabled(false);
            counter =  percent + 6.25 ;
            counter2 = percent2 + 1;
        }
        if(questfivedone==true)
        {
            btl5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f2);
            btl5.setEnabled(false);
            counter =  percent + 6.25 ;
            counter2 = percent2 + 1;
        }
        if(questsixdone==true)
        {
            btl6.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f6);
            btl6.setEnabled(false);
            counter =  percent + 6.25 ;
            counter2 = percent2 + 1;
        }
        if(questsevendone==true)
        {
            btl7.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f10);
            btl7.setEnabled(false);
            counter =  percent + 6.25 ;
            counter2 = percent2 + 1;
        }
        if(questeightdone==true)
        {
            btl8.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f14);
            btl8.setEnabled(false);
            counter =  percent + 6.25 ;
            counter2 = percent2 + 1;
        }
        if(questninedone==true)
        {
            btl9.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f3);
            btl9.setEnabled(false);
            counter =  percent + 6.25 ;
            counter2 = percent2 + 1;
        }
        if(questtendone==true)
        {
            btl10.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f7);
            btl10.setEnabled(false);
            counter =  percent + 6.25 ;
            counter2 = percent2 + 1;
        }
        if(questelevendone==true)
        {
            btl11.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f11);
            btl11.setEnabled(false);
            counter =  percent + 6.25 ;
            counter2 = percent2 + 1;
        }
        if(questtwelvedone==true)
        {
            btl12.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f15);
            btl12.setEnabled(false);
            counter =  percent + 6.25 ;
            counter2 = percent2 + 1;
        }
        if(questthirteendone==true)
        {
            btl13.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f4);
            btl13.setEnabled(false);
            counter =  percent + 6.25 ;
            counter2 = percent2 + 1;
        }
        if(questfourteendone==true)
        {
            btl14.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f8);
            btl14.setEnabled(false);
            counter =  percent + 6.25 ;
            counter2 = percent2 + 1;
        }
        if(questfifteendone==true)
        {
            btl15.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f12);
            btl15.setEnabled(false);
            counter =  percent + 6.25 ;
            counter2 = percent2 + 1;
        }
        if(questsixteendone==true)
        {
            btl16.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f16);
            btl16.setEnabled(false);
            counter =  percent + 6.25 ;
            counter2 = percent2 + 1;
        }

        result.setText(counter + "%");
        result2.setText(counter2 + " out of 16");
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: why is all of that in a try?

Comment: Those exceptions lurking in the dark. You never know man, you never know. (Yes, I'm joking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace percent to counter
and percent2 to counter2.